# Windows Service SearchIndexer.exe Crashes on Indexing

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, services, microsoft-outlook-2010

**Relevant Specs**:

- Windows 7 Professional 64-bit SP1
- Outlook 2010 Version 14.0.7116.5000 (32-bit)

**Original Symptom**:
In outlook, I attempted to search for an email but nothing ever returned and the indicator kept going like it was searching.

**Attempted Resolutions**: I investigated the search options and with some research noticed the Windows Service "Windows Search" (SearchIndexer.exe) was not running.

[image: Services window]

I attempted to start it but I receive this error message: "Windows could not start the Windows Search service on Local Computer. Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly."

The Event Viewer gives this error entry:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          6/3/2014 11:02:05 AM
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      ***REMOVED FOR POST***
Description:
Faulting application name: SearchIndexer.exe, version: 7.0.7601.17610, time stamp: 0x4dc0d019
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18229, time stamp: 0x51fb1677
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000000940d
Faulting process id: 0x6a0
Faulting application start time: 0x01cf7f3cc83757c6
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\system32\SearchIndexer.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 06424160-eb30-11e3-9555-843a4b07b336
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-06-03T15:02:05.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>602923</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>***REMOVED FOR POST***</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>SearchIndexer.exe</Data>
    <Data>7.0.7601.17610</Data>
    <Data>4dc0d019</Data>
    <Data>KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
    <Data>6.1.7601.18229</Data>
    <Data>51fb1677</Data>
    <Data>c0000005</Data>
    <Data>000000000000940d</Data>
    <Data>6a0</Data>
    <Data>01cf7f3cc83757c6</Data>
    <Data>C:\Windows\system32\SearchIndexer.exe</Data>
    <Data>C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
    <Data>06424160-eb30-11e3-9555-843a4b07b336</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

The regular windows search (from start menu) works fine, and if I reboot the machine the service starts up OK but as soon as it kicks off when I let the machine idle for long enough it crashes (same Event Viewer entry).

We also tried the Microsoft Utility to no avail.  Has anyone seen this issue before?

Comment: `We also tried the Microsoft Utility to no avail` - What Microsoft utility?

Comment: It was this [MS Fix It](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/windows_search/en-us)

Comment: follow this and give me the dump: http://pastebin.com/gYV6vWHJ

Comment: @magicandre1981 The link says it is a private paste

Comment: I fixed it. Try to open it again

Comment: @josh Try removing some entries from the indexing, and see if it still crashes - maybe you'll get a clearer view.

Comment: Not sure if this will be of any help? - I saw 'Error 1067' and 'The process terminated unexpectedly' on Windows 10 just a day ago. It turned out the root cause was that I was having a dll file in C:\Windows\System32 (AudioEndpointBuilder.dll) with a different build version than my current build of Windows 10, which is build 10.0.17134 (= version 1803). The dll that caused Error 1067 had version 10.0.14393. Once I replaced the bad dll with one having the same version as my current build, 10.0.17134, the service started working fine again. In your case, I would look closer at `KERNELBASE.dll`.

Answer (score 0):

This solve for my case:
problem:  windows search    service   start  and crash
windows 11 very slow,  and lag on different place of explorer shell

resolution:  delete C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Search\Data\Applications\Windows\Windows.edb
and restart service.   now w11 is responsive, no more lag,  service is up.

enjoy

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).